# InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/redirect', 'SocialAuthController@redirect');
    Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthController@callback');
});
```

app.php

```
  'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

session.php

```
'domain' => 'localhost:8000/',
```

services.php

```
 'facebook' => [

    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/callback',
],
```

SocialAuthController

```
public function redirect()
{
    return \Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();

    //return $providerUser;
}


public function callback(SocialAccountService $service)
{
    $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());
    var_dump($user);
    dd($user);
    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect()->to('/home');



}
```

Error

[InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZY4a.jpg)

Comment: Look there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153717/socialite-invalidstateexception-in-abstractprovider-php-line-191/45487932#45487932

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the state cookie is not being set.

Try set the domain to null and driver to cookie in session.php.