# Socialite: InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 191

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I have the [same](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/socialite-invalidstateexception-in-abstractproviderphp) issue. But I don't know what I have to do.

Socialite works at the localhost, but on the webserver it doesn't work. Laravel 5.4.

This stroke returns null at the AbstractProvider.php:

```
$state = $this->request->session()->pull('state');
```

Comment: Are you redirect the callback at the correct route

Comment: yes. But it can create this error? I have the local route as http://project.local but my route on the server named as http://name.name1.site.com

Comment: So changed your routes if you are hosting it on,the server..

Comment: I have changed routes like a second route on previous comment.

Comment: Are you getting the callback on that route..?

Comment: Yes. When I confirmed on the social network, it redirected me to the route with state and code params in GET. It looks like:
.../callback/vkontakte?code=a43e2eaf52cb5ca3bc&state=WvdDr9wxop39xSZ4aGMrDuRYt3fsnfGsHYF305sO

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `asPopup` method? Try save session then `session()->save();`
or you just can try this:

```
session()->put('state', request()->input('state'));
Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
```